# Sending a data from android phone to pc?

Tags: c#, java, android, networking

I am creating a "tracking system" for my android phone. Basically, the phone would transmit it latitude/longitude to a C# program that will receive the coordinates and display it on a map. I managed to get the phone's latitude/longitude coordinates but I need a way to transmit that data to my C# application running in my PC. I know my way around C# and Java but never really got into network programming. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into C# Webservices, very powerful. The communication protocol is SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) which is a popular and well supported standard.

Good starting reference: [Your first C# Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service)

Comment: I'd also suggest making use of the ARO tool which is free and can help you to optimize your application network usage to make sure the performance is the best it can be. https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700312

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the C# side of it, but if you write a C# server to receive post requests, the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) makes it relatively simple to send requests. There are a bunch of other questions on SO that will help with setting up the client side on your phone if you poke around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have different way to do it.

- The first is to send data over the cloud to interact through  distant server. So the both devices have to be connected to Internet
- The second id to send the data over a local network so the data have to be on the same network and have to share their IPs
- The third is to use [adb forward](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports) which allows to build a socket connection between the 2 devices over a USB cable. The requirements are that the phone have to be on debug mode I think and that the driver are installed on the PC so the phone is recognized by ADB.
- I can add one more by using a Bluetooth connection. Find information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it would be to build WCF service which allows many different protocols to receive data. This would could be a very powerful solution that can be extended in future.

The fastest and easiest IMO would be to create ASP.NET MVC application, define a POCO Model for your longitude/latitude and create an action that would take your Model as parameter. Then use HttpClient and  HttpPost on android to send the data. The trick here is to name the variables in your post request same as ones you define in your C# Model.